# Using a string parameter in terminal

Tags: command-line, nmcli

What's wrong with this command:

```
nmcli c up uuid  "$nmcli -t -f uuid c"
```

How can I fix it?

`"$nmcli -t -f uuid c"` is a uuid needed after `nmcli c up uuid`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
nmcli c up uuid  "$(nmcli -t -f uuid c)"
```

Use backticks or `$(cmd)` for [commmand substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst)

Note that `nmcli -t -f uuid c` can print out more than one `uuid`. I didn't test it yet, but the command above might not work then. If so, you should make sure that you are using the right `uuid` like that:

```
nmcli c up uuid `nmcli -t -f name,uuid c | awk -F':' '/^YOURWIFINAME:/{print $2}'`
```

Comment: in the second case I prefer to run `nmcli c up uuid` for all available uuids. I think a `for` loop may be needed and something that can get each uuid separately as a string.